# How to integrate a java web application with Apple Calendar

Tags: java, spring, calendar

I want to integrate my web application with calendar provider like **Google-Calendar**, **Microsoft-Outlook** and **Apple-Calendar**.
I could to integrate my web application with Google and Microsoft. Steps for each of them is:

1. Create an App in Provider console/portal and get Client-Id and Client-Secret.
2. Config my web application for connecting to Provider in OAuth2 standard.
3. User authenticate with own username (email) and password and return `refresh_token` and `access_token` to my web application.
4. Use the `access_token` and `refresh_token` for get Calendar events.

But for Apple Calendar I am confused. I could not find Apple OAuth2 or any API for get Calendar Events.

Can anyone help me?

:(

Of course read an article about Apple app-specific-password but I don't know how it's working and could not find any example with this option.